# ROS 1 or 2 in ROS Lunar?

Tags: ros2, ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS2 has been around for a while. I would like to know which distribution is actually using ROS2? I looked at the Lunar distribution [website](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar) and did not see the specification about its ROS kernel.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285694/ros-1-or-2-in-ros-lunar?/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2018-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS 2 is (at the moment) a completely separate project, and ROS 1 releases do not share anything (roughly) with ROS 2.

Currently supported ROS 1 releases are Indigo, Kinetic, Lunar and Melodic (see [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) and [wiki/Distributions](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions)).

The only currently supported ROS 2 release is Ardent (see [ros2/ros2 - All Releases](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Releases) and [ros2/ros2 - Roadmap](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Roadmap)).

So to answer your questions:

> I would like to know which distribution is actually using ROS2?

That would be only Ardent at the moment, and the Summer 2018 release in the near future.

> I looked at the Lunar distribution website and do not see the specification of its ROS kernel.

Anything currently listed on `wiki.ros.org` is ROS 1 specific. So none of the currently supported ROS 1 releases use anything from ROS 2.

---

Edit:

> I thought that ROS 1 or 2 to each distribution is like Linux kernel to its distributions.

No, that is not how things are designed. While it would be nice, that is currently not possible.

I would say that a tagged set of the whole of ROS 1 or ROS 2 are the distributions. I don't believe an analogy with the Linux kernel and the various Linux distributions can be made.

> Maybe should I say Ros core?

That would be ambiguous, as `ros_core` is the name of one of the ROS 1 *variants* or [metapackages](http://wiki.ros.org/Metapackages) defined in/by [REP 142](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0142.html) (specifically: [Specification - Metapackages - ROS Core](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0142.html#ros-core)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-17**:\

> ROS kernel

I don't believe there is such a thing as the "ROS kernel". Or at least not in the traditional sense of the word *kernel* ,when used in an operating systems context.

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2018-03-17**:
I thought that ROS 1 or 2 to each distribution is like Linux kernel to its distributions. Maybe should I say Ros core?